# What does this say? (I want to see how easy/difficult this code is)

Tags: cipher

I made a code and I want to test out the difficulty, so can anyone figure out what this says?

.1852132114 51415 775 14920 18582015 18582095 11149820 5255 .191852020512 2018158 18522518156 412158 5255

Comment: no clues or any hints?

Comment: Regarding **how difficult it is**, I don't really know anything about codebreaking, but I'm looking at it and immediately seeing: "5255" twice, four strings that start with "185", and two periods and no other special characters, possibly indicating the end of a sentence (and given their position, that the message has been reversed)

Comment: @Mekalikot Nope

Comment: @question_asker It has been reversed ^_^

Comment: I didn't put an answer in because the question doesn't interest me a ton, but it is based on turning letters into numbers, where A = 1 and Z = 26, then backwards (based on where the periods are).  5255 = "eye" (5,25,5) and 1852132114 = "number" (14,21,13,2,5,18).  I didn't go further than that.

Comment: Without even knowing what the message is trying to convey, this question is more *uninteresting* than difficult.

Answer (score 6):

What I have here still sounds a little jumbled, so it's possible that there's a mistake or two in there, but I think a couple of the commenters had the right idea.

> If you split up each number correctly, then as Daphne B says in the comments, you just map A to 1, B to 2 and so on. Split the numbers like so: 
>  
>  18-5-2-13-21-14 5-14-15 7-7-5 14-9-20 18-5-8-20-15 18-5-8-20-9-5 11-14-9-8-20 5-25-5 .19-18-5-20-20-5-12 20-18-1-5-8 18-5-22-5-18-15-6 4-12-15-8 5-25-5 
>  
>  and convert to letters. 
>  
>  .REBMUN ENO GGE NIT REHTO REHTIE KNIHT EYE .SRETTEL TRAEH REVEROF DLOH EYE 
>  
>  As question_asker posited, it looks like the message is reversed, so reverse it back and you get 
>  
>  EYE HOLD FOREVER HEART LETTERS. EYE THINK EITHER OTHER TIN EGG ONE NUMBER. 
>  
>  or in more readable terms, "**I hold forever heart letters. I think either other tin egg one number**" 
>  It's entirely possible that I screwed up decoding part of it; in particular the final message stops making sense after "either."

Comment: You're nearly there :) There's just one more step.

Comment: I think it should be "I hold forever love letters"

Comment: @Mekalikot That'd make sense as a next step, certainly

Comment: @Mekalikot Kind of getting there a bit more